# SpringMVC send email

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send email using SpringMVC. I've made a bean JavaMailSender and get an error.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(){
  JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
  javaMailSender.setUsername("test");
  javaMailSender.setPassword("test");
  javaMailSender.setPort(56);
  javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.test.ru");
  return javaMailSender;
}
```

Error:

04-Dec-2016 20:05:50.699 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(31)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender

My context with this bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:util.properties")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:auth.properties"})
public class MailContext {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setUsername("test");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("test");
        javaMailSender.setPort(556);
        javaMailSender.setHost("test.ru");
        javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

My pom :

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you starting your application? Is it a web-app running under Tomcat? A command line app being started with `java ...`? Something else?

Comment: start from IntelijIDEA with TomCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need, but do not have `spring-context-support-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar` on your classpath.

To add this to your application's classpath in IntelliJ, edit your project's `Project Structure`, and add a `Library` under `Libraries` referencing the Spring jar file. Add or edit your `Module` and add the library to the `Module`. Add or edit `Artifacts` and make sure the library or module is one of the `Available Elements` for the `Artifact`.

Under the `Run` menu, click `Edit Configurations` for your Tomcat configuration, on the `Deployment` tab, add the artifact (or library) to the `Deploy at server startup` list.

[This information at JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) provides more information on configuring your Intellij setup to get desired jars on your classpath.

It is also possible that you need to make a simple configuration change to your dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

(NOTE the addition of the `<scope>` element. [More information on Maven scopes available here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).)

(These instructions may vary depending on the version of Intellij that you are using.)

In summary, you need to get the Spring jar on your application's classpath at runtime.